# Caching data from api using useFetch in my Nuxt 3 application because it is slow

Tags: javascript, postgresql, caching, nuxt.js, prisma

**What i'm building**
I'm making a Nuxt 3 project where i list my played chess games. These games are stored in a postgreSQL database and i use Prisma to query them.

**Problem summary**
The page where i fetch my games is not caching the data and is therefor very slow (i also get i nice  in my network tab in Firefox). The data will not be updated that often, i will probably end up just manually fetching games from the chess.com API and put these in my database whenever i played a few games. I'm not sure if this problem is in the `useFetch` i use or Prisma.

**What i want**
I want this data to be available to me instantly when i navigate to this page. I think caching is the thing i want, but not sure. Open to suggestions on how to do this. Also would appreciate answers that explain to me how this works, or where i could find more information on this topic.

**What i tried**

- I played around with the [options](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch) for `useFetch` like `initialCache: true`, or use `useAsyncData` instead.
- I tried to see if this is something that is also happening when just returning some data from a JSON (see Stackblitz below) because i thought this might be a Prisma thing when i query stuff from the database. Seems like this is just the way it works either way.
- Watched [some video's on fetching](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rU92oLYjTGY) in a Nuxt app, learned some stuff but not about caching.

**My application**
The basic structure of my app looks something like this:

`pages/index.vue`

```
<script setup>
const { data: games } = await useFetch("/api/games");
</script>

<template>
  <div class="page-title">
    <h1>Games</h1>
  </div>
  <Table v-if="games" :games="games" />
  <div v-else>No games found.</div>
</template>
```

`server/api/games/index.get.js`

```
import prisma from "./prisma";

export default defineEventHandler(async () => {
  const games = await prisma.games.findMany({
    include: {
      moves: {
        orderBy: { id: "asc" },
      },
    },
    orderBy: { id: "asc" },
  });
  
  return games;
});
```

I also made a StackBlitz with a basic structure of my application:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-2p4dab?file=server%2Fapi%2Fgames.json